# Waiting icon on Ionic mobile app

Tags: android, iphone, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

Its been frustrating since we tried many times but failed to resolve the issue on our mobile app (build on Ionic Framework + html5 + AngularJS). When our mobile app is activated, it tries to display data for selection (service layer built on Python), but somehow, the waiting icon is displayed for a long time. Due to confidentiality issue, I cannot display the mobile app code here, but I hope someone how share their experience on this issue. I am attached a copy of the screen shot for reference. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W00F.png). All positive suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

[Mobile app waiting icon issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W00F.png)

Comment: are you using $ionicLoading service?

Comment: areuse ionic2 or ionic 1 with ?

Comment: We are using ionic 1, and Yes, we are using Ionic Loading Service.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but from what I understood you can hide the loader in your callback function. I have assumed you are using promise/callback

```
$ionicLoading.show();
var datacall=//your call to a data service function using $http to your backend
datacall.$promise.then(function(success){$ionicLoading.hide()},function(err){$ionicLoading.hide()});
```

Let me know if you want the entire code

Comment: Thanks Raj. Basically, my problem is the connection related issue. When user activates our mobile app (assuming the user has already login previously with the user id and password cached in our mobile app), the mobile app runs, but with the problem of trying to retrieve the first data from our MySQL server (ready for selection). SOmehow, this loading is indefinitely and there is NO control how long the loading will take. Many time, I have to kill the app and re-start it again for a few times before the loading issue goes away.

Comment: When does the loading start and when do you want it to be hidden?

Comment: The mobile app loading starts as soon as the user turns on the mobile app. This will trigger a connection from the mobile app to retrieve data from our MySQL server. SOmehow, this data fetching and populating of data into a drop down box takes too long and as a result, the "waiting" icon appears. I don't need the "waiting" icon to be hidden, but I need the mobile app to appear now (not in a state of waiting). Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey Raj, is there a better way that I can reach you for a discussion?

Comment: you can mail me at rnsharma@zodiva.com